# LoginUser Win32 API function return success even if domain is incorrect

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to authenticate user programmatically using WIN32 API in C++. I am facing an issue, if user enter correct user name and password but incorrect domain, the LoginUser API is returning success. My expectation is in case of any mismatch be it User Name, Password or Domain, LoginUser API must return failure. Am I having incorrect expectation. My development PC is not in any domain i.e. domain - > '.'

```
bool Authenticate::authenticateUserCommandLine(string userName, string password, string domain, string& returnMessage)
{
    HANDLE  token;
    BOOL    logonReturnVal;
    trim(userName);
    trim(password);
    trim(domain);
    if(domain.length() == 0)
        domain = ".";
    if(password.length() == 0)
        logonReturnVal = LogonUser(userName.c_str(), domain.c_str(), NULL, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token);
    else
        logonReturnVal = LogonUser(userName.c_str(), domain.c_str(), password.c_str(), LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token);

    if(!logonReturnVal)
    {
        returnMessage = Error::GetLastErrorAsString();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        returnMessage = "AuthenticationSuccess";
        return true;
    }
}
```

userName = "Test"   (Correct)

Password = "abcdef"   (Correct)

Domain   = "Hardware"   (In-correct) instead of "."

Comment: Are you sure that `domain` does not become empty after call to `trim` and actually hold proper value at the point of `LogonUser` invocation?

Comment: I have checked  using gdb, String domain contains Hardware.

Comment: Try `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` flag?

Comment: @Maximus, Sir the solution didn't work.